# Conflict between requireJS and LoadJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, requirejs

#### Background:

I'm currently using Webpack to bundle the newly developed components on top of an existing system which uses RequireJS to load the legacy components.

#### Issue:

I'm trying to import JS libraries dynamically with LoadJS to increase the performance of the platform. However, it's conflicting with RequireJS.

I've used jQuery [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and [$scriptjs](https://github.com/muicss/loadjs); both results in the same error.

`$(...).Modal is not a function.`

My JS is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".js-my-btn", function(){
        loadjs("https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", () => {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
})
```

#### JsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/umarmw/rkb3yzv9/34/) **without** RequireJS

**Libraries loaded**:

- [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js)
- [LoadJS](https://unpkg.com/loadjs@3.5.5/dist/loadjs.min.js)

Upon clicking on the button, the modal is displayed. It works fine.

#### JsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/umarmw/rkb3yzv9/35/) **with** RequireJS

**Libraries loaded**:

- [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js)
- [LoadJS](https://unpkg.com/loadjs@3.5.5/dist/loadjs.min.js)
- [RequireJS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js)

Upon clicking on the button, the modal is not displayed. It throws an error.

Note: Loading RequireJS before LoadJS doesn't work.